# reading xml from gz file

Tags: php, xml, gzip

i have a link that point on to xml.gz file on the web, i am trying to get the xml out and read him.

i tried:

```
$path = '/temp_xml/test.xml';
$url  = 'http://feeds.###########_UMXILI.xml.gz';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL => $url
, CURLOPT_HEADER => 0
, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1
, CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip'
));
```

do i must save the data at temporary file on my computer in order to decode? and how?
thanks

Comment: did you tried `echo curl_exec($ch);` the output should be already decoded - that is the feature of using `CURLOPT_ENCODING => 'gzip'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to save the file, you can pass it to `gzdecode($string)` and it will return uncompressed string:

```
$compressed = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$uncompressed = gzdecode($compressed);
// now you can use string as xml
$xml = simplexml_load_string($uncompressed);
```

Comment: hmm i tried that and i am getting:   
"Fatal error: Call to undefined function gzdecode()"

Comment: @user2706762 yes, you obviously are using older PHP version since function is available from version PHP 5.4

Comment: @user2706762 I forgot to see you are already using `CURLOPT_ENCODING` gzip, there fore curl should already decode the string and you should be able to use it as xml